# How to represent $x^y$ = [Integer] + [Remainder]?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**For example**: $5^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2.23606\ldots = 2 + 0.23606\ldots$
Can we do this for $x^y$ in general?

**Motivation**: a way of expressing the floor, $ \lfloor x^y\rfloor $, of an exponential $x^y$ using algebra.

Note: $x,y \in \mathbb{R} > 0$

I'm thinking that maybe the trick may involve generating a power series of $x^y$ and somehow extracting terms that represent the integer and remainder parts, but otherwise I'm stuck.

Any comments/answers/suggestions/edits would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

-*McMath.*

Comment: You can do this for any real number: just express $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$. It's not an enlightening result, but it is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Directly using the binomial theorem: we can write (for $x,y \geq 0$) $$x=k+r \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}, r  \in [0,1)$$ $$y=\ell+s \qquad \ell \in \mathbb{N}, s  \in [0,1),$$ we see that $$x^y= (k+r)^s(k+r)^{\ell} = k^s(\underbrace{1+\frac{r}{k}}_{\in [1,2)})^s \sum_{i=0}^{\ell} \binom{\ell}{i} k^{\ell-i}r^i.$$ Thus, $\lfloor x^y \rfloor$ ulimately depends on $r=\{x\}$ and $s=\{y\}.$

My bet is there is no formula that does not involve all four of $\lfloor x \rfloor , \lfloor y \rfloor, \{x\}, \{y\}.$

Comment: Dzoooks, thank you, that's a brilliant explanation. I appreciate you taking the time to post such a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find anything.  Let $5^x=6.9999, 5^y=7.00001$.  $x$ and $y$ are very similar, but the integer part of the power is different.  Powers are nicely continuous but floor functions are not, so they don't want to play together nicely.

Comment: Ross, yeah floor functions are pesky. In mathematica, there's a HoldForm instruction that carries a variable or function without evaluating it, and I created a function for myself to do this, wherein the floor of x equals x minus the fractional part of x multiplied by an appropriately defined step function. In my view, what makes floors so nasty at times is that they lose information, which can make certain computations in math intractable. Thank you for your answer response, I appreciate your viewpoint.